# p4vasp on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fails

Tags: python, gtk

I recently tried to install p4vasp. I tried to compile it from downloaded files from their website and also from Ubuntu Software. both ways install it right and I can run it, so far so good. I load a desired file and it works, but as soon as I try to open structure viewer or DOS, I get this message in terminal:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/p4vasp/applet/GraphWindowApplet.py:266: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_set_events: assertion '!gtk_widget_get_realized (widget)' failed
x.set_events(event_mask)
```

I cannot find any way to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've seen many warnings running some GTK-Applications. Why do you think you need to resolve it? Is something not running the way it should?

Comment: Yes unfortunately the program doesn't work as it should. The plots are wrong and in the viewer I see only one atom in position 0,0,0 instead of all atoms in the cell. The problem seems to be in this module for visualization